How to instantiate fragment views in Android?
In a detail layout, I added a tab layout with multiple tab items using fragments.

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/greenish"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnSearch"
        app:tabBackground="@color/light_green"
        app:tabSelectedTextAppearance="@style/TabSelectedStyle"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/dark_green"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabStyle"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/details_tab_label">

The tab item layouts have textviews to show various parts of the search results. I added tabselectedlistener etc and the result is that when the activity opens, it shows me my search field and button, I can search and it loads the data.
At this point, when I try to set the textview values inside the fragment, I get a null pointer exception. This is because the layouts belonging to the tabs have not yet been inflated. If, before searching, I selected each tab, then the values may be set.
To handle this, I added to the main activity's onCreate:
        // Loop and set all tabs so as to inflate their views
        for(int i = tabLayout.getTabCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

However, this feels the wrong way of doing things.
Also, for some reason, the active tab is always the 4th one instead of the first one.

I once did something like this but I used a different approach which in my opinion sounds a bit easier in my mind.
Instead of forcing the tabs to switch and waiting for them to inflate, we can ensure the fragments update when they become visible. Here's how we can do it:
First setup a ViewPager with a fragment pager adapter. the adapter should look something like this:
private String[] tabTitles = new String[]{"Tab1", "Tab2"}; //add more tabs

public FragmentPagerAdapter2(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new Tab1Fragment();
        case 1:
            return new Tab2Fragment(); // add more cases for other tabs
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabTitles.length;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabTitles[position];
}

After that we can just update the UI when they become visible, easy. it should be something like this:
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {
        // Update your UI here
        updateUI();
    }
}

private void updateUI() {
    if (textView != null) {
        textView.setText("Data here");
    }
}

I copy pasted code from my previous working project here. Hope it works for you.

My ViewPager code is identical. However, as I said, on my opening screen I have a search box with a search button and the tab layout is below that. The search fills out the results on multiple tabs. Hmmm... it occurs to me that I shouldn't fill the results when they are retrieved, but put them into shared variables in the main activity and use the onCreateView of the fragment to read from them. Let's try it that way.

That sounds good. Storing search results in shared variables in the main activity is much more organized and clean. Great thinking. I'll try it in future.

setUserVisibleHint is deprecated. The documentation says to use onResume. I am converting to that.
